# I try to install something, telling me to add -r flag, I do and still tells me to

Tags: debian, minecraft

when I try to install Pocketmine, It tells me to add the -r flag, i do, still tells me the same thing, picture.

[image]

Comment: The answer given by steeldriver should work for you.  It is worth remembering to scrub your personal data (in this case your IP address) anytime you are post anything publicly.

Comment: Please copy-paste the text instead of posting a screenshot. Screeshots are hard to read, can't be searched, and can't be copied from.

Answer (score 2):

You are **downloading a script** using `wget` and **running** it by piping the result to `bash`: the script  is telling you to add `-r` to the invocation of the script, **not** to `wget`.

Probably the easiest solution is to take the script's advice, i.e.  run it as a normal user; either by opening a new PuTTY session as a regular user, or using `su`

```
su - someuser
wget -q -O - ... | bash
```

Alternatively, you could save the script instead of piping it to bash, and then run it directly using whatever user and command-line options you wish.

Comment: When I do -r in | -r bash it says -r: command not found. Am I doing it right?

Comment: No that's not going to work AFAIK. There *may* be a clever way to add the `-r` flag in a piped invocation, but I can't think of one. In the meantime, easiest way is probably to save the script (replace `wget -O -` by `wget -O somescript`) and run it after (`chmod +x somescript; ./somescript -r`).

Comment: I'm root but it wont let me run the script?